# Eiffel: red, green, blue, foo, bar: INTEGER is unique

Tags: eiffel

I remembered that I was able to do something like

`red, green, blue, foo, bar: INTEGER is unique`

in Eiffel, is it obsolete? for what reason? What does replace it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique constant attributes are now obsolete. A new type-safe mechanism is under development. Meanwhile, the closest alternative is to use constant attributes:

```
red: INTEGER = 1
green: INTEGER = 2
blue: INTEGER = 3
foo: INTEGER = 4
bar: INTEGER = 5
```

Of course, it's also possible to design a type-safe variant yourself:

```
expanded class QUX inherit
    ANY
        redefine
            default_create
        end 
feature {NONE} -- Creation
    default_create do make (1) end
feature {QUX} -- Initialization
    make (value: like item) do item := value end
feature -- Enumeration
    red: QUX
        once
            Result.make (1)
        ensure
            instance_free: class
        end
    green: QUX
        once
            Result.make (2)
        ensure
            instance_free: class
        end
feature -- Access
    item: INTEGER
end
```

Then in the code you would write:

```
x: QUX
...
x := {QUX}.red
if x = {QUX}.green then ...
```

**Note.** You may need to install EiffelStudio 18.07 or later to use class features.

Comment: Is there any documentation about the obsolescence reason?

Comment: @Pipo There is no documentation. The original mechanism with unique has several issues: 1) it is not type-safe (i.g. one can assign a unique value to a variable and then compare it to a unique value from a different declaration); 2) there is no control on the assigned values (the values are generated by the compiler, and different compilers did it differently); 3) as a consequence of 2, one can mistakenly use integer intervals based on unique values that would work differently from one compilation to another or from one compiler to another.

Comment: Actually, I think the cleanest implementation of a so called enumeration is to be descendents of a parent class so that it could be checked by the compiler. I don't see any example where its not the case. But it more time consuming and generating more files than doing it with enumerates in terms of programming.